# How to decrement like $dec?

Tags: meteor

In the Meteor leaderboard example there is this line:

```
  Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
```

How can I gracefully decrement the same field? Sadly, there is no $dec.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

MongoDB allows you to [increment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) by negative values:

```
$inc: {score: -1}
```

Answer (score 8):

From the MongoDB docs (linked to from the Meteor docs):
The $inc update operator accepts positive and negative values. A negative value effectively decrements the specified field.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Answer (score 4):

You can apply this code:

```
$inc: {
  score: -1
}
```

apply negative values (-1, -3, -5 and so on ) for decrement value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of something like $dec. 
A negative value effectively decrements the specified field. For example using (`-value`):

```
Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: -value}});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: -1}});
```

you can simply use negative value (ex : -1, -2, -3, .....) for decrement value in mongo collection

Answer (score -1):

#### JS

`db.test.update({id: "zxf"}, {$inc: {intValue: NumberInt(-1)}});`

#### Java

`Update update = new Update().inc(field, -1);`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.